# how to find middle element of array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have Question in my interview that how to find middle element of array in javascript **without using length method and loop** .From my point of view without length we can find the `middle` element but without loop we can't find .

I tried like that but I didn't get correct out .I got `4` but expected is `3`

```
var arr =[1,2,3,4,5];

function middleElement(arr){

var i=0,
 j=i+2;
 while(arr[j] !=null){
     i++;
     j=i+2;
 }

return arr[i]
}

middleElement(arr);
```

Comment: what means without loop? is it allowed to destroy the array?

Comment: I think it mean we can't use `for` loop

Comment: from my perspective the same goes for while loop

Comment: how to <is it allowed to destroy the array>> destroy the array

Comment: `From my point of view without length we can find the middle element ` can you justify this first @user944513

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I tried as above withoutt length

Comment: But you said without loop we can't. And that's what I am showing from my answer. That without loop also we can get the middle e,ement

Comment: You can get total number of elements for example `arr.indexOf(arr.slice(-1)[0]);` or `arr.reduce((r) => r += 1, 0);` and then just divide that by / 2

Comment: @NenadVracar I'd personally consider this as the best answer. However, interview questions are notoriously obtuse - sometimes they check if you know about existing solutions like your own other times they will go "We wanted you to write the functionality from scratch" which, IMO, is quite stupid. Well, unless mentioned specifically but even then, it should be for something simpler, so you don't have to come up with a solution that's weird for the sake of being weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it using recursion:

```
var array = [1,2,8,4,5];

function middle(i) {
    if (array[i] !== undefined) {
       return middle(i+1);
    } else {
       return array[Math.floor(i / 2)];
   }
}

console.log(middle(0));
```

Comment: I would use `if (i in array)` if array can contain `[undefined]` elements, but I can't think of any way to handle missing elements like `[,1,]`

Comment: This is actually using recursion to get the `length` of the array.

Comment: Indeed, but we are not using loops or length directly, right?)

Answer (score 3):

If the array values are **unique**, you can reverse the array. And compare it with the original array. Where it match is the center.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var middle = [...arr].reverse().reduce((c, v, i) => {
  if (v === arr[i]) c = v;
  return c;
}, null);

console.log(middle);
```

---

If you reduce is also not allowed, you can do recursion

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let findMiddle = (a, b, i) => {
  if (a[i] !== b[i]) return findMiddle(a, b, i + 1);
  return a[i];
}

let middle = findMiddle(arr, [...arr].reverse(), 0);

console.log(middle);
```

Comment: Well it is still kind of looping because reduce uses loop under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an recursive approach by popping and shifting the array. Then get the last value, which is unequal to `undefined`.

```js
function getLeft(array, last) {
    var value = array.shift();
    return value === undefined ? last : getRight(array, value);
}

function getRight(array, last) {
    var value = array.pop();
    return value === undefined ? last : getLeft(array, value);
}

function getMiddle(array) {
    return getRight(array.slice()); // take copy for destroying.
}

console.log(getMiddle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

A concise approach with a flipflop for pop/shift methods.

```js
function getMiddle(array) {

    function takeItem(i) {
        var value = a[['pop', 'shift'][i]](); 
        return 0 in a
            ? takeItem(1 - i)
            : value;
    }

    var a = array.slice(); // take copy for destroying
    return takeItem(0);
}

console.log(getMiddle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to find the middle element when the `.length` is even number, and in certain cases where the `.length` is higher than the number of elements.  For example, `.length` of `[,,1,,,]` is 5 and the middle element is 1, but that can't be determined without the `.length` property.
That being said, here is a small improved version of the accepted answer:

```js
function getMiddle(array, i = 0) {
    if (i * 2 + 2 in array) return getMiddle( array, i + 1 )
    else return array[i];
}

console.log( getMiddle( [, 2, 3, 4] ) )    // 2
console.log( getMiddle( [1, 2, 3, 4] ) )   // 2 (or 3?)
console.log( getMiddle( [1, 2, 3, , ,] ) ) // 2, but should be 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count =0;
function func(arr){
    if(arr[count] != undefined) {
        count++;
        func();
    }
}
func();
console.log(arr[count/2]);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code, code-only answers tend to not be useful to other readers and will attract downvotes. If you explain how your code works and why it's a good solution to this problem, you will have a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Solution to this will be `middle = arr[parseInt((arr.length-1)/2)]` this will give middle number to the nearest whole number